# Windows Store Localise App Name in Tile

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-store

How do I localise the Application name in a Windows Store App so that its localised name appears in the App Tile?

Setting the Display name as per this article does not work.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454044.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you use the *string resources*, it can use that translation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465254.aspx